# C# line code translation to VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, byte

Hello I'm translating a new code from C# to Vb.NET and I'm getting an error and I Can't figure out what it is:

this is my c# line:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MAKV2SPBNI99212", new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
```

This is my VB.Net line:

```
Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MAKV2SPBNI99212", New Byte() {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76})
```

This is the error that I'm getting: 
Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

That is happening in the new byte array

any idea where is the issue?

Comment: `0x` is not a valid identifier in VB use `&H`

Comment: Awesome!! thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# uses `0x` and VB.NET uses `&H` to specify hexadecimal numbers. try this.

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes("MAKV2SPBNI99212", New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
```

Comment: @JavierSalas I'm glad, it helped. Please vote and mark this as solution if it helped and is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 0x by &H like : 0x49 -> &H49

This is the major difference I can see when I translate the code here :
http://converter.telerik.com/